# Ambiguous Subscript Emitted By The Compiler

Tags: swift

```
    extension Array {
    subscript(externalIndex index: Int) -> (String, String)? {
        guard let value = self[index] as? Int else {
            return nil
        }
        
        switch (value >= 0, abs(value % 2)) {
        case (true, 0): return ("positive", "even")
        case(true, 1): return ("positive", "odd")
        case(false, 0): return ("negative", "even")
        case(false, 1): return ("negative", "odd")
        default: return nil
            
        }
    } 
}

extension Array {
    subscript(i: Int) -> (String, String)? {
        guard let value = self[i] as? Int else {
            return nil
        }
        
        switch (value >= 0, abs(value % 2)) {
        case (true, 0): return ("positive", "even")
        case(true, 1): return ("positive", "odd")
        case(false, 0): return ("negative", "even")
        case(false, 1): return ("negative", "odd")
        default: return nil
            
        }
    }
}
```

The question is how come the first script work with the external index listed in the parameter list but the second script won't work without the external index?

It just keeps saying ambiguous use of subscript. These are the scripts extracted from the book as I am still learning swift.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the form `subscript(someVariableName: Int)` is the same as `subscript(_ someVariableName: Int)`, which is essentially overwriting the already existing Array subscript without a parameter name - hence you get the ambiguity warning when using the `self[someVariableName]` accessor.

You need to explicitly give the parameter an external and internal name to avoid this.

See for example https://www.avanderlee.com/swift/custom-subscripts/.

Comment: Question follows: Does it mean that the already existing Array subscript is the same as subscript(_ someVariableName: Int)? The reason why subscript(someVariableName: Int) is the same as subscript(_ someVariableName: Int) in the eye of the compiler is because subscript does not require the use of parameter name in the argument list when we call or use the subscript?

Comment: yes - when you define `subscript(someVariableName: Int)` you use it like `array(index)` (without parameter name), which is the same as the already existing subscript function